# wget to parse a webpage in shell

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I am trying to extract URLS from a webpage using wget. I tried this

```
 wget -r -l2 --reject=gif -O out.html www.google.com | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'
```

It is displaiyng FINISHED

```
  Downloaded: 18,472 bytes in 1 files
```

But not displaying the weblinks. If I try to do it seperately

```
  wget -r -l2 --reject=gif -O out.html www.google.com 
  sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' < out.html
```

Output

```
  http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/            
  /intl/en/policies/terms/
```

It is not displaying all the links

```
ttp://www.google.com
http://maps.google.com
https://play.google.com
http://www.youtube.com
http://news.google.com
https://mail.google.com
https://drive.google.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
https://plus.google.com
```

And more over I want to get links from 2nd level and more  can any one give a solution for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shell is a command processor intended for simple automation. Please consider switching to real programing language like python (available by default on all major linux distros), java, c++, perl etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-O file` option captures the output of `wget` and writes it to the specified file, so there is no output going through the pipe to `sed`.
You can say `-O -` to direct `wget` output to standard output.

Comment: Got the first level but unable to parse the next levels using wget -r -l2

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use grep, you can try

```
sed -n "/href/ s/.*href=['\"]\([^'\"]*\)['\"].*/\1/gp"
```

Comment: its not displaying the output as i required